# for what values of parameters p,q does the integral $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^p + x^q}dx$ converges?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

What I thought is to break this into different cases:

1. $p=0$: so the integral given ~ $\displaystyle \int_1^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^q}$ , and it converges for $q>1$.
2. $p<0$: so the integral given ~ $\displaystyle\int_1^{\infty}\frac{dx}{\frac{1}{x^p}x^q}$~$\displaystyle\int_1^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^q}$ (when $x\rightarrow\infty$), and again it converges for $q>1$.
3. $p > 0$: what happens here?

Im not even sure im doing the right thing in any of these cases.

would love getting some help from you guys.
thanks

Comment: I'd say you need $\max(p,q)>1$.

Comment: If $p>0$ then check if its greater thatn $q$

Comment: One of the first thigs you have to notice in such a question is the symmetry in $p$ and $q$. I mean your question stays the same if you exchange the two variables. In your answer you can then replace $p$ with $q$. It is always a powerful view.

Comment: Got it, so after rewriting as stated below, can I say that in this case p is the dominant parameter and for p>1 it converges?

Comment: You recieved an answer to your question. Is it what you needed? If so, consider *accepting* the answer. That's how the site works. If it is not what you needed, please explain what is still left unclear.

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**:

Assume, for now, that $p\geq q$ (the case when $q>p$ will be more or less identical, so for now, this assumption is safe).

You can then rewrite

$$\frac{1}{x^p+x^q} = \frac{1}{x^p(1+x^{q-p})}$$

and note that $q-p \leq 0$. A similar rewrite can be done if $q>p$.

---

Note that you don't really need the splitting of cases I did above. Strictly speaking, you can always rewrite

$$\frac{1}{x^p+x^q} = \frac{1}{x^{\max(p,q)}(1 + x^{\min(p,q)-\max(p,q)})}$$

however this makes the idea behind the solution harder to see in my opinion.

Comment: Okay, so here's what I did from that point: (Assumin p>q)
$\frac{1}{x^p+x^q}=\frac{1}{x^p(1+x^(q-p))}$
So the dominant is $x^p$ and I can say that $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^p}$ converges when p>1.
is that correct?

Comment: @OacRoland Looks good. Did you also examine what happens if $p\leq q$?